# Adobe Illustrator, two objects, want to subtract one from the other

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have two objects in Illustrator, a black circle and the silhouette of a person (in white).
I want to subtract the silhouette from the black circle. So that everything but (what is left of) the black circle is transparent.
How do I do this?

Comment: Did you first google the exact title you used for this question...?

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods.

**1.**  Compund Path

*Object* > *Compound Path* > *Make* (<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>)

---

**2.** Pathfinder

*Window* > *Pathfinder* (<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>)

Select your objects, then *Minus Front* in the Pathfinder Panel

[image]

That will remove the silhouette shape from the circle - leaving it blank (transparent).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but both aren't working.

The first option gives me this response:
"Can't make a compound path. All objects in a compound path must be paths, and they cannot be brushed or be part of an object."

The second, I select both objects hit the subtract command in Pathfinder window, it looks no different and I get:
The filter produced no results. Please select two intersecting paths."

Any other ideas?

Comment: @AdobeSoup Ungroup your stuff first.